# How do you pass several arguments to R function in opencpu

Tags: javascript, r, opencpu

I have a function that expects a json as input input and several arguments as below:

```
data<-function(x, listname=NA) {
  x<-fromJSON(x)
  (x <- lapply(x, function(x) { as.data.frame(x) }))
  (x <- do.call(rbind, x))
  x<-unique(x)

  cols <- listname
  dd<-cbind(Date=x[,1],subset(x, select=cols))
  mm <- melt(dd)
  ss <- split(mm, mm$variable)

  poo <- unname(Map(function(n,x) 
    list(name=n, data=unname(lapply(split(x, 1:nrow(x)), function(x) {
      list(x$Date, x$value)
    }))), names(ss),ss))
  p<-toJSON(poo)
  return(p)
}
```

This data function expects x as a json format and bunch of other arguments.

In opencpu framework:

I build my argument list called param based on selected list items as below:

```
var values = [];
      $("#yaxis option:selected, #xaxis option:selected").each(function() {
      values.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
      });
      param="c(" + values.join(",") + ")";
      console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
        mysession.getObject(function(data){
          var data5=JSON.stringify(data);
          var req1 = ocpu.call("data", {
            x:data5,
            listname:param
```

console.log(param)

```
"c(\"Server1\",\"DateTime\")"
```

when I make this call, I get this error:

```
OpenCPU error HTTP 400
unused argument (listname = "c(\"Server1\",\"DateTime\")")
```

when I run this function on the R console as this,

data(x, listname=c("Server1","DateTime")

it works perfectly.

Do I need to do anything more on javascript to format param output?

Comment: I should ask, why this doesn't seem like javascript, I am missing some detail ?

Comment: simple suggestion , what if you change the name of function (use something like data_func)...?

Comment: @dseminara, I am using javascript and R backend to do some work. I build my param, pass that to an R function. It looks like my param list is wrongly formatted. The function call data takes argument like this: data(x,c("CPU","DateTime"). When I do console.log, I see quotes around my param variable, that may be the culprit, how do you remove that?

Comment: @agstudy, I changed the name of the function from data to data_func, I get this error: OpenCPU error HTTP 400
undefined columns selected

In call:
`[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop)